# Reactjs: Pass same props to multiple components

Tags: reactjs

I'm kind of new to reactjs and I'm trying to do a bit of clean up. I was wondering how I could use spread attributes for props provided by the new context api? `<Today />` and `<All />` will basically use the same props and I thought it looked pretty messy.

Here are the lines I wanted to clean up:

```
     <ResultsProvider>
        <ResultsContext.Consumer>
          {(val) => (
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path={'/'} render={ (props) =>
                  <Today
                    results={val.results}
                    loading={val.loading}
                    viewTicket={val.viewTicket}
                    formatStatus={val.formatStatus}
                    fetchData={val.fetchData}
                    formatDate={val.formatDate}
                    sortResults={val.sortResults}
                    formatTitle={val.formatTitle}
                  />
              }/>
              <Route path={'/week'} component={Week} />
              <Route path={'/all'} render={ (props) => 
                  <All
                    results={val.results}
                    loading={val.loading}
                    viewTicket={val.viewTicket}
                    formatStatus={val.formatStatus}
                    fetchData={val.fetchData}
                    formatDate={val.formatDate}
                    sortResults={val.sortResults}
                    formatTitle={val.formatTitle}
                  />
              }/>
            </Switch>
          )}
        </ResultsContext.Consumer>
      </ResultsProvider>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since both the components need to be passed the same props, you can create an object and then pass it to the components using spread syntax like

```
<ResultsProvider>
    <ResultsContext.Consumer>
      {(val) =>  {
        const customProps = {
           results: val.results,
           loading: val.loading,
           viewTicket: val.viewTicket,
           formatStatus: val.formatStatus,
           fetchData: val.fetchData,
           formatDate: val.formatDate,
           sortResults: val.sortResults,
           formatTitle: val.formatTitle
        }
       return  <Switch>
          <Route exact path={'/'} render={ (props) =>
              <Today
                {...props}
                {...customProps}
              />
          }/>
          <Route path={'/week'} component={Week} />
          <Route path={'/all'} render={ (props) => 
              <All
                {...props}
                {...customProps}
              />
          }/>
        </Switch>
      }}
    </ResultsContext.Consumer>
  </ResultsProvider>
```

Comment: Dang, didn't know it was that easy. I tried doing it earlier but I somehow always get an error. Thanks a lot! By the way, what would happen if I choose to remove `{...props}` ?

Comment: `{...props}` are the router props, which a component needs if you use `Link` or `this.props.match` etc inside it

Comment: Ohh interesting. Thanks a lot for the help again, mate! :)